# "Things are N1, N2, N3" or "Things are with N1, N2, N3"?

Tags: grammaticality

I wrote a sentence in my article:

> *The most important things are: practicability, simplicity*

however my friend told me that the sentence should be:

> *The most important things are with practicability, simplicity*

which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I were editing the article I would suggest that it be changed to: "The most important things are practicability and simplicity". There is no need to use the colon for a list comprising two items, nor a comma to separate them. I would also suggest that "practicality" be considered instead of "practicability", but not knowing the context I cannot advise which would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct and the second is incorrect as used here.
When providing a list of attributes or actions it would be more usual to separate them with commas for all except the last two and to use "and" between the last two. eg "The dragon was large, green, scaly, slimy and very large".

The second version is similar to correct usage using the same base words in a somewhat different way.

You could say

> The most important thing is to act with practicality* and simplicity"

*Note that I used practicality instead of practicability as the latter **might** be correct (almost) but would be so unusual as to sound forced.

It would be correct, albeit somewhat unusual to say:

> Practicability and simplicity are the most important things to consider.
>   (Or - ... to take account of.)